# Displaying value from struts2 list in html table

Tags: html, struts2

I have a Struts2 List consisting of date and a status. Ex.

```
listDate - listStatus 
12/12/12 - A 
13/12/12 - B 
14/12/12 - C 
15/12/12 - D 
16/12/12 - E 
17/12/12 - F 
18/12/12 - G 
19/12/12 - H
```

I want to display this as a table in `html`.

The `listDate` should be the header of the column and the `listStatus` should be the data value.

And each row should consists of only a specified number of column , say 5.

ex like this

```
12/12/12 13/12/12 14/12/12

   A        B        C
```

etc

I used the iterator tag for the same as follows :

```
    <s:iterator value="listvalues" var="lstdata" status="status">
    <s:if test="%{#status.index == 0}">
        <tr><td><s:property value="#lstdata.listDate"></s:property></td></s:if>
    <s:elseif test="%{#status.index%7 == 0}">
        </tr><tr><td><s:property value="#lstdata.listDate"></s:property></td>
    </s:elseif>
    <s:else>
    <td><s:property value="#lstdata.listDate"></s:property></td>
    </s:else>
```

The above code could lists the date in rows with each row containing 7 dates.

My requirement is to place the status below each date.

Also the the columns should begin with sundays and end with saturdays.

So in case the list of dates begin with tuesday, the data in the first 2 cells should be empty, but should display the corresponding date.

I could do this inside the action class by creating seperate lists for 7 days but would like to know if there is a way out for this using html/`Struts2` tag...please send in your thoughts.

Comment: please try to format your code

Answer (score 1):

You should do this:

1. Build your own bean:

```
class MyBean {
    Date date;
    String status;
}
```

2. Fill your bean with `List<MyBean> list` and make sure it starts with Sunday (try `java.util.Calendar`)

3. Show your bean using `<s:iterator>`

```xml
<tr>
    <s:iterator value="list" var="var" status="status">
        <s:if test="#status.index%7==0"></tr><tr></s:if>
        <td>
            <s:property value="#var.date"/><br/>
            <s:property value="#var.status"/>
        </td>
    </s:iterator>
</tr>
```

Comment: Jaiwo99, sure..just another question, is it possible to display the status as another cell below the date...right now both are on the same cell..

Comment: @user1999559 why you wanna them in separated cell? you can do it using another tag like `div` or build another table in the `td`, but your data should be wrapped in the same unit! everything is possible, but i don't see a reason to do it

Comment: Its because I want the data to be displayed as a table with the dates in a row, which i would mark as a header and the status below the date which would be displayed as a rectangle in different colours depending on the status codes. Hence if the status is displyed in a different cell, it would be possible to specify the colours for that cell.

Comment: @user1999559 try this <span style=""><s:property/></span><br/><span  style=""><s:property/></span>